# При нажатии "поделиться" в Google Play ссылка на приложение постить без деталей

Tags: google-play, facebook

В этом собственно и весь вопрос. Ссылку предоставляю согласно документации `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<"package_name">`, однако в Facebook постится только иконка приложения и его название, без деталей и описания. Выглядит совершенно непривлекательно для пользователей. Как исправить?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать этим запросом. Он не рабочий ибо не правильно записан. И ... это самый странный вопрос  который я видел. Во первых не сюда писать нужно, а в facebook почему они описания игры по ссылке не добавляют. И прочтите справку этого сайта.

Comment: Прошу простить, а разве вопрос не понятен? в саппорт ФБ обращалась, пока безрезультатно. Помогли разработчики в комьюнити девелоперов. Но так как решение ещё не реализовано, то и апдейт я здесь не пишу.  А в чем странность, позвольте поинтересоваться?:) И хотелось бы узнать, что же "во-вторых":)

Comment: А во вторых задавайте вопросы подходящие по тематике для этого сайта и если уж создали аккаунт то будете активны;)